# routing a only specific traffic through a vpn connection via python

Tags: python, vpn

Is there any method to connect to vpn through python and have that traffic of that application only route through the said VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Python itself can't be used to route traffic; though you can use it to execute system commands to change your routing table.  If you're on Linux, you need to use the `ip` command from the iproute2 and `iptables` from netfilter to change the routing behavior of specific traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Please, be more specific in your question. Generally, yes, it is possible.

If you use python 2.7 or newer, you can use `source_address` option for http connections (see reference for libraries you use) as tuple `('interface address', port)`.

If you use sockets in your app, use `socket.bind(('interface address', port))` on created socket before `socket.connect()`.